# How to get operator rights in ircd-hybrid?

Tags: server, ubuntu-14.04, irc

I have installed ircd-hybrid on Ubuntu Server 14.04.2, it is running and I can connect. But when I try to /oper, I do not get operator rights, it is simply saying "Only few of mere mortals may try to enter the twilight zone". Did I configured it wrong? Or is it just impossible to /oper from over the internet and it is only allowed on the local network?

My configuration in the ircd.conf file is the standard besides this changed entries:

```
auth {
    user = "*@*";
    class = "users";
    password = "secret";
#   flags = need_ident;
};
#operator {
    name = "op";
    user = "*@*";
    password = "hello";
    encrypted = no;
    class = "opers";
}
```

I connect as a normal user with password "secret" to the server and try to get rights with

```
/oper op hello
```

Any suggestions what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operator tag is commented out. Replace the "#operator {" with "operator {" and then try again after rehashing the ircd with a SIGHUP.

Comment: What a silly mistake -.- . Thanks for the simple solution, it worked!